# Error "Operation failed for reasons unrelated to the database..." when using indexedDB in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I've tried back and forth between different examples in FF, and all i get is `The operation failed for reasons unrelated to the database itself and not covered by any other error code.` I believe its caused by `var request = indexedDB.open("mydb",2);`

```
  var db;

  var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB 
                ||window.mozIndexedDB||window.msIndexedDB;

  var request = indexedDB.open("mydb",2);    

  customerData=[
    {ssn:"444-44-4444",name:"Bill",age:35,email:"bill@company.com"},      
    {ssn:"555-55-5555",name:"Donna",age:32,email:"donna@home.org"}
  ];

  request.onerror = function(event){

  };
  request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {

     var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("customers",{keyPath:"ssn"});
     objectStore.createIndex("name","name",{unique:false});
     objectStore.createIndex("email","email",{unique:true});

     for(var i in customerData){
        objectStore.add(customerData[i]);
     }
  } ;
  request.onsuccess = function(e) {

  } ;
```

Thanks

Comment: Possibly caused by file inadvertently locked for writing within the Firefox profile: https://github.com/webcompat/web-bugs/issues/118366

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you open this html/js script?

If I recall correctly FF can not open indexedDB from `file.html`
It's a bug or a feature depending of a view point.

Try using xampit or other "server". Or just do quick test with Chrome.

Comment: Yes, i actually figured it out before the answer :) But on a webserver it works. Thanks though

Comment: Meaning, that IndexedDB could be served only over http(s):// URLs, not file:// Which means, that IMHO this answer is wrong and the following right.

Comment: Probably neither of any of the above explain the problem.  I think it's caused indirectly by a file locked for writing within the Windows file system.  But until Mozilla improve their diagnostics, we will not know - e.g. knowing which file is locked would be a start.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I tried to open a file "locally".
I found on MDC a post saying that by security reasons any operation with indexedDb will be only available by a request via a webserver.
So it seems the problem doesn't have nothing related to file name (namelly file.html) but with protocol.

Answer (score 1):

There's an open bug on BugZilla about this curious error message:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1628125

It's possible it arises due to hard disk corruption, but is not clear.

We'd like Mozilla to improve their diagnostics, and not go in the direction of a "Sorry, something went wrong" generic error message that product management think is more user-friendly - it isn't, and is no more helpful than a [WSOD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_of_death).